# Linear Resolution of a Hibi Ring

Tags: combinatorics, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

I have read somewhere that a Hibi ring has a linear resolution if and only if it's regularity is 1. Please refer me the proof of this fact.

Firstly, I need to define the Hibi ring.
Let $L$ be a finite distributive lattice and let $P$ be the subposet of $L$ which consists of the join-irreducible elements of $L.$ Then,
by a famous theorem of Birkhoff, it follows that $L$ is isomorphic to the lattice  $\mathcal{I}(P)$ of the poset ideals of
$P.$ Let us assume that $P$ consists of $n$ elements, say $P=\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$. Let $A=K[t,x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be the polynomial ring in $n+1$
variables over a field $K.$   The Hibi ring of $\mathcal{I}(P)$ is the $K$--sublagebra $R[L]$ of $A$ generated over $K$ by the monomials
$u_{\alpha}=t\prod_{p_i\in \alpha}x_i,$ with $\alpha\in L.$

$R[L]$ is an algebra with straightening laws
on $L$ over $K$.
Let $B=K[\{x_\alpha: \alpha \in L\}]$
be the polynomial ring in the indeterminates indexed by the elements of $L.$ Then, the defining ideal $I_L\subset B$ of the toric ring $R[L]$ is generated
by the straightening relations, namely
$$I_L=(x_\alpha x_\beta-x_{\alpha\cap \beta}x_{\alpha\cup \beta}: \alpha,\beta \in L, \text{ incomparable}).$$
$I_L$ is called the Hibi ideal  or the join-meet ideal of $L.$

Comment: What's a Hibi ring?

Comment: @Bernard I have edited the question in the reply of your comment.